# React: show and hide different components from different files

Tags: reactjs, button, components

I have rooted components like this:

```
<Container>
   <Text1/>
   <Text2/>
<Container>
```

I want Text 1 to show when Text 2 is hidden and vice versa.

Text 1 is a component in the same file and is first hidden. Text 2 is an exported component from a different file, and inside Text2 component theres a button that once clicked, hides text2 completely. However, how do I trigger Text 1 to be shown from the Text2 file once the button is triggered?

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage the state in the parent component which will decide which text should be displayed

```
const Container = () => {
      const [text, setText] = useState("text1")

      const onClickHandler = () => {
            if(text === "text1"){
                setText(text2) 
            } 
            setText(text1)
      }

      return (
            <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Display {text === "text1" ? "text1" : "text2"}</button>
            {text === "text1" ? <Text1 /> : <Text2>}
      )
}
```